# QTreeView insert item, insert child item

Tags: c++, qt

I use QTreeView component for writing programs.

```
ui->treeView-> ...
```

How add item and child item to QTreeView?

Answer (score 3):

I made by QTreeWidget:

```
// Create new item (top level item)
QTreeWidgetItem *topLevelItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
// Add it on our tree as the top item.
ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(topLevelItem);
// Set text for item
topLevelItem->setText(0,"Item");
// Create new item and add as child item
QTreeWidgetItem *item=new QTreeWidgetItem(topLevelItem);
// Set text for item
item->setText(0,"SubItem");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `QAbstractItemModel` and use the `setModel()` of `QTreeView` to set the model.

[Here is an example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)